# Affine transformation not composing with translation as expected

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, matrix, transform

Well, the title isn't completely accurate. The transformation I am dealing with is a perspective transformation that can be very well approximated as an affine transformation--yet it doesn't produce results close to what I'd expect of an affine transformation, and even when I *do* use a pure affine transformation the results are still modify the translation part of the transformation in unexpected ways.

I start with `numpy` arrays, representing transformation matrices, as follows:

```
transformation = np.array([[.5, .1, 40],
                           [.06, -.18, 725],
                           [.00003, .00001, 1]])

real_affine= np.array([[.5, .1, 40],
                       [.06, -.18, 725],
                       [0, 0, 1]])

translation = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                        [0, 1, 50],
                        [0, 0, 1]])
```

Then I compose them, expecting to get (at least approximately) this as a result for `transformation.dot(translation)`:

```
np.array([[.5, .1, 40],
          [.06, -.18, 775],
          [.00003, .00001, 1]])
```

and this one for `real_affine.dot(translation)`:

```
np.array([[.5, .1, 40],
          [.06, -.18, 775],
          [0, 0, 1]])
```

That is, the same exact transformation with the y translation value modified. Instead, I get this:

```
>>> transformation.dot(translation)
array([[  5.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e-01,   4.50000000e+01],
       [  6.00000000e-02,  -1.80000000e-01,   7.16000000e+02],
       [  3.00000000e-05,   1.00000000e-05,   1.00050000e+00]])

>>> real_affine.dot(translation)
array([[  5.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e-01,   4.50000000e+01],
       [  6.00000000e-02,  -1.80000000e-01,   7.16000000e+02],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00]])
```

What's going on here? It is the same exact transformation (aside from the translation) but the translation values are out of whack with what I'd expect.

Apologies for my ignorance, I've never formally studied matrices or transformations. The answer may well be extremely obvious.

Comment: Your `transformation` is not affine. The last row of an affine matrix must be `0 0 0 ... 0 1`. As such, it does not commute with translation.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include that the first translation is approximately affine so I was wondering why I would get a result so far off from what I'd expect of an affine transformation. I edited the question to include `real_affine`, which is an affine translation and still doesn't produce the desired results

Comment: I still do not understand your expectations. An arbitrary affine transformation _in general_ does not commute with translation. The only affine transformations that commute are translation to translation, rotation to rotation about the same axis, rotation to uniform scaling, and scaling to scaling.

Comment: By "commute" what do you mean? That they produce the same result when multiplied no matter the order? If so, that isn't my question. I'm just wondering why they aren't composing as I described, as I would have thought that all matrix transformations (even perspective transformations) do.

Comment: Your assumption is in general wrong. You essentially claim that adding affine matrices is the same as multiplying affine matrices, which is obviously false.

Comment: Do homographies not compose then?